# Obtener Valor de un XML(XSD) con PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

Me conecto a un servicio SOAP que me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="dsPDFGuia" targetnamespace="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd" attributeformdefault="qualified" elementformdefault="qualified"><xs:element name="dsPDFGuia" msdata:isdataset="true" msdata:usecurrentlocale="true"><xs:complextype><xs:choice minoccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Guia"><xs:complextype><xs:sequence><xs:element name="Inicial" type="xs:long" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="Final" type="xs:long" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="BytesImagen" type="xs:base64Binary" minoccurs="0"></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:sequence></xs:complextype></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complextype></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><dspdfguia xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd"><guia diffgr:id="Guia1" msdata:roworder="0"><inicial>290005680</inicial><final>290005680</final><bytesimagen>ARCHIVO_CODIFICADO_BASE64</bytesimagen></guia></dspdfguia></diffgr:diffgram>
```

Para lo que necesito utilizar el contenido de la etiqueta **bytesimagen** pero no se como obtener este valor desde PHP. Obteniendo este valor ya se como decodificarlo y utilizarlo para mostrar el pdf, pero me estorba todo el codigo xml.

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito dar un [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de buscar y buscar no consegui un buen metodo. Sin embargo utilice mi sentido comun y utilizando **str_replace** de php quite todo el codigo que me estorbaba (**XSD**), quedando solo el archivo binario para luego decodificar y mostrar. A continuacion dejo el codigo que le dio solucion para que pueda ser consultado por otra persona!!

```
$pdf = str_replace('<xs:schema xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="dsPDFGuia" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"><xs:element name="dsPDFGuia" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Guia"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="Inicial" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Final" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="BytesImagen" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><dsPDFGuia xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsPDFGuia.xsd"><Guia diffgr:id="Guia1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><Inicial></Inicial><Final></Final><BytesImagen>',"",$pdf);
$pdf = str_replace('</BytesImagen></Guia></dsPDFGuia></diffgr:diffgram>',"",$pdf);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
echo base64_decode($pdf);
```

Answer (score -1):

Sin tener información de tu codigo o del servicio, se me ocurren dos soluciones posibles, la primera es utilizando expresiones regulares y [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$xml = /* Aquí va tu XML */;

$xmlData = preg_match("/(?s)(?<=\<bytesimagen\>)(.*?)(?=\<\/bytesimagen\>)/", $xml, $matchesXML);

$b64 = array_pop($matchesXML); // Este es el valor que necesitas
```

La siguiente opción es utilizando [simplexml_load_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) y es mas correcta pero deberías corregir el XML que expones ya que devuelve error, indicando que hay contenido extra que no debería estar allí.

```
$xml = /* Aquí va tu XML */;

$xmlData = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), 1);

$b64 = $xmlData['dspdfguia']['guia']['bytesimagen']; // Este es el valor que necesitas
```